# PHP Session Array - Query Database

Tags: php, database, arrays, session

This is a follow on to a previous question.

I have 4 buttons on my home page, each has their own ID associated to them. When someone clicks a button Jquery grabs the button ID and sends it to PHP via Ajax where it is then added as a session variable. If people click multiple buttons it will send the ID of each button.
So in the end it is possible that I could have 4 variables in the array.

The Session is created as an array so that it can hold the multiple ID's:
Like so:

```
 <?php
    session_start();

    if ( ! is_array( $_SESSION['ids'] ) ) {
       $_SESSION['ids'] = array();
    }

    if ( ! in_array($_POST['session'], $_SESSION['ids'] ) ) {
       $_SESSION['ids'][] = $_POST['session'];
    }
 ?>
```

That all works correctly and If i `print_r $_SESSION['ids']` it correctly shows the id of each button that was clicked and stored e.g:

```
[0] => 1, null, [1] => 3, null, [2] => 4
```

(Where the button id's that were stored are 1, 3 and 4.

The issue now is that I need to query the database for the button ID's that have been stored.

How can I break the array up and get just the values e.g: The button `ID 1, 3` and `4`.
So that I can query the database with them?

Comment: You can use for loop to traverse the buttons session array. What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `implode()` function, described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
$in = implode(',',$_SESSION['ids']);
mysql_query("SELECT * from yourbd where id in ($in)");//just an eg. mysql_* is deprecated
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
$buttons=$_SESSION['ids'];
$str=implode(', ',$buttons);
$sqlquery = mysql_query("Select * from table where btn_id IN ($str)");
```

Comment: The issue with that is it then returns the ID's as a single number:

E.g: Gets ID 1 and 3 but it places them as 13.

Comment: @JPDP ok. can you please print the array $_SESSION['ids'] and paste  it here

Comment: Print_r = Array ( [0] => [1] => 1 [2] => 3 )


And the echo: 13

Comment: @JPDP Sorry, I still do not understand. Do you mean that if you use the code in my answer, you are getting 13?

Comment: Thats right, so your code is getting the 2 Id's that are stored in the sessions (in this example they are ID 1 and ID 3. So the output is 13. When I try to query the databse for $btn it thinks I mean 13 instead of 1,3

Comment: @JPDP Try this:foreach($buttons as $btn) 
{ 
     echo $btn; echo '<br>'; 
     echo $query="select * from table where btnid='$btn'";              echo '<br><br>';
 } Paste the result here.

Comment: That does put them on a seperate line, so they are no 1 and 3 respectively. Is there a way just to comma seperate them?

I tried replacing <br> with , in your new code however it also adds a , before and after each number

Comment: @JPDP  $buttons=$_SESSION['ids']; echo $str=implode(', ',$buttons); This will do. You can write the query like $sqlquery = "Select * from table where btn_id IN ($str)";

Answer (score 0):

### Change Array

```
  foreach ($IdsArray as $myId) {
    $newIds[] = 'my_id = ' . $myId;
  }
  $orSeparatedIds = implode(" OR ", $newIds);
```

### Use in Query

```
$query = "select my_id from mytable where $orSeparatedIds";
```